# Optimal way to "stamp" string into desired string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, algorithm

So, I was looking for an algorithm for the following problem:

You are given a desired string **s**, and a stamp **t**. **t** is also a string. Let the beginning string be `len(s)*"?"`.

Is it possible to use the stamp to transform the beginning string into the string s using the stamp? The whole stamp must fit inside the beginning string (the stamp's borders may not exceed the ?????... string's borders).

Print the number of stamps required and print the left border of the stamp for each stamping.

**Example:**

```
AABCACA (desired result)

ABCA (stamp)

Solution:
3
1 4 2
explanation: ??????? → ABCA??? → ABCABCA → AABCACA.
```

**My solution:**
If the stamp's first letter is not the desired string's first letter, the task is not possible. The same goes for the last letter. If the stamp doesn't have all the letters in the desired string, the task is impossible.

My algorithm goes like this: try to find the stamp in the desired string. If it is found, delete it and replace it with question marks. Mark down the left border of the stamp. Do this as long as you can.

Then look for the stamp's contiguous subarrays of size len(stamp)-1. If you find any of those, delete them and replace with question marks. Mark down the left border of the stamp.

Then look for the stamp's contiguous subarrays of size len(stamp)-2. If you find any of those, delete them and replace with question marks. Mark down the left border of the stamp. Do that until you are finished. There you have the answer.

**The problems**
I'm not sure what is wrong with my code as it can't seem to pass some test cases. There is probably a logical error.

```
import sys

desiredString = input()
stamp = input()
stampingSpots = []

if (len(set(desiredString)) != len(set(stamp)) or stamp[0] != desiredString[0] or stamp[-1] != desiredString[-1]):
    print("-1")
    sys.exit()


def searchAndReplace(stringToFind, fix): #Search for stringToFind and replace it with len(stringToFind)*"?". Fix is used to fix the position.
    global desiredString
    for x in range(0, len(desiredString)-len(stringToFind)+1):
        if desiredString[x:x+len(stringToFind)] == stringToFind:
            stampingSpots.append(x+1-fix) #Mark down the stamping spot
            firstPart = desiredString[:x]
            firstPart += len(stringToFind)*"?"
            firstPart += desiredString[len(firstPart):]
            desiredString = firstPart
            return True
    return False

while(searchAndReplace(stamp,0)): #Search for the full stamp in desiredString
    searchAndReplace(stamp,0)



length = len(stamp)-1
while(length > 0):
    for firstPart in range(0, len(stamp)-length+1):
        secondPart = firstPart+length
        while(searchAndReplace(stamp[firstPart:secondPart], firstPart)):
            searchAndReplace(stamp[firstPart:secondPart], firstPart)

    if len(stampingSpots) > 10*len(desiredString): #Too much output, not possible
        print("-1")
        sys.exit()
    length -= 1


print(len(stampingSpots))    
for i in reversed(stampingSpots):
    print(i, end = " ")
```

Comment: I would try overstamping and understamping. Overstamping means appending a number to the output. Understamping  means inserting a number at the beginning of the output. Using this technique, the answer is `[4,1,2]`. Explanation: the initial output is `[1]` giving string `ABCA???`. Overstamping is applied giving `[1,2]` and string `AABCA??`. Then understamping is applied giving `[4,1,2]` and string `AABCACA`.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm you describe is fundamentally flawed. The results it produces simply don't correspond to things the stamp can actually do. For example, with stamp `AB` and string `AAA`, it will try to stamp beyond the borders of the string to apply the final `A`. It will also try to use use the `AB` and `BC` substrings of the stamp `ABC` directly next to each other for the string `ABBC`, but no actual application of the stamp can do that.

The stamp cannot be used to apply arbitrary substrings of the stamp string. It can be used to stamp over previous stamp applications, but your algorithm doesn't consider the full complexity of overstamping. Also, even if you could stamp arbitrary substrings of the stamp string, you haven't proven your algorithm minimizes stamp applications.

Answer (score 0):

We can use divide and conquer: let `f(s)` represent the minimum stamps required to generate string `s` where "*" is a wildcard. Then:

- Geedily pick a part of the string that's the largest match for the stamp.
- Set that part to wildcards and provide each of its right and left parts to `f`.

For example:

```
AABCACA (desired result)
ABCA (stamp)

f(AABCACA)
   ^^^^
   ABCA (match)

= 1 + f(A****) + f(****CA)

=> f(A****)
     ^^^^
     ABCA (match)

=> f(****CA)
       ^^^^
       ABCA

Total 3
```

Comment: @Quiti I have no idea. The divide-and-conquer seems to me pretty convincing. The greedy part is more of a guess, might need some testing :) Do you have a place to submit code, or some test cases?